# Detect when database has started

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Node.JS server, with a MongoDB database. I start the database within Node.JS as follows:

```
(function startDatabase() {
    exec('killall -15 mongod; mongod --dbpath ./db', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('Database error! Aborting.');
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });
}());
```

The problem with this approach is that I have no way of knowing that the database has successfully started, because `mongod` never returns (unless there is an error), so I never get to see `stdout`.

How can I start the MongoDB database within Node.JS and detect when it has started?

Comment: You could do a `exec('ps aux | grep mongod')` and detect the output of it, you could also get the pid back and use `ps` to see if that process is running.

Comment: It is strange that your system does not provide a way to manage services.
What is your system ?

Comment: You mean OS? It's Red Hat EL 6.

Comment: `killall` is a rather brute force way to shutdown MongoDB as you will kill all matching processes on the box that you have permission to kill (i.e. possibly some not started by this Node.js instance).  You would be better using a [`service` definition](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#control-mongodb) to start/stop politely.  If you want to wait until the database is started you could add a startup loop to try connecting to MongoDB and sleep until the connection is accepted (or a timeout has been exceeded).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do :

```
service mongod status    //check status
service mongod start     //start
service mongod stop      //stop
service mongod restart   //restart
```

or instead of `service mongod` `/etc/init.d/mongod`

startDatabase should use `service mongod start` not kill the service and then start. It is not graceful close and you can loose data/corrupt files. If you want to restart it then use `service mongod restart`. But check status to stop or restart.